# How to fill in the grouping 'gaps' to make a table?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html

I've been puzzling  over a way to matrix / pivot my data into an HTML table with C# in a MVC view.

It seems I can get off to a good start with grouping, then grouping within the group to generate the tags and data:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead class="thead-inverse">
    <tr >
        <th></th>
        @foreach (var responsiblityGroup in @Model.PAssets.GroupBy(x => x.Responsibility))
        {
            <th>@responsiblityGroup.Key</th>
        }
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach (var typeGroup in @Model.PAssets.GroupBy(x => x.Type))
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@typeGroup.Key</td>

        @foreach (var responsibiltyGroup in typeGroup.GroupBy(x => x.Responsibility))
        {
            <td>@responsibiltyGroup.Count()</td>
           }
        </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

But obviously I was left with problem off not having a cell for the groups with no items, and data incorrectly sitting in the first column available i.e.

[image: Missing cells]

Is there any way, I wonder, to force display these groups with a count of 0?

**EDIT**

Following comments I tried constructing data in a table first:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myList = new List<ListItem>();
        myList.Add(new ListItem("IT", "Cat"));
        myList.Add(new ListItem("IT", "Cat"));
        myList.Add(new ListItem("IT", "Owl"));
        myList.Add(new ListItem("DE", "Dog"));
        myList.Add(new ListItem("BU", "Cat"));
        myList.Add(new ListItem("BU", "Dog"));
        myList.Add(new ListItem("BU", "Dog"));
        myList.Add(new ListItem("PR", "Dog"));
        myList.Add(new ListItem("PR", "Owl"));

        var roleGroup = myList.GroupBy(x => x.Role).OrderBy(y => y.Key);
        var roleGroupNo = myList.GroupBy(x => x.Role).Count();

        var typeGroup = myList.OrderBy(x => x.Type).GroupBy(x => x.Type);
        var typeGroupNo = myList.GroupBy(x => x.Type).Count();

        var roleGroupHeader = new string[roleGroupNo];


        var roleIndex = -1;
        foreach (var header in roleGroup)
        {
            roleIndex++;
            roleGroupHeader[roleIndex] = header.Key;
        }

        var typeGroupHeader = new string[typeGroupNo];

        var typeIndex = -1;
        foreach (var header in typeGroup)
        {
            typeIndex++;
            typeGroupHeader[typeIndex] = header.Key;
        }

        var dataGrid = new int[roleGroupNo, typeGroupNo];

        foreach (var item in myList)
        {
            int x = Array.IndexOf(roleGroupHeader, item.Role);
            int y = Array.IndexOf(typeGroupHeader, item.Type);

            dataGrid[x, y]++;
        }
        Console.Write($"    ");
        for (int i = 0; i < typeGroupNo; i++)
        {
            Console.Write($"{typeGroupHeader[i]},");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        for (int i = 0;  i < roleGroupNo; i++)
        {
            Console.Write($"{roleGroupHeader[i]},   ");
            for (int j = 0; j < typeGroupNo; j++)
            {
                Console.Write($"{dataGrid[i, j]},");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }



        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class ListItem
{
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public ListItem(string role, string type)
    {
        this.Role = role;
        this.Type = type;
    }
}
```

[console result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uD9pP.png)

Comment: It sounds like you need to massage this data into a different structure **before** you get to your view.  Your razor shouldn't be handling such heavy lifting

Comment: @maccettura Yes, I did start wondering if that was all a bit much for the view - especially with 3500 records. I can change my viewmodel but i'm struggling to visualise the structure I need to recreate the table.

Comment: Make a class that represents all the columns in a single row, then make a collection of that class.  Then just iterate through it in your view.  It may help for you to add more code or explain what the current model is / what it represents.

Comment: I contemplated something along those lines, but do you mean hard coding the roles (art, IT, etc.)? The only drawback with that is we might well have more / fewer of them in future. The model represents items in a college inventory, each of which has (amongst other things) a type, and somebody responsible for it.

Comment: From what I am understanding you need a count of specific devices, per role right?  So if you had a class called `DeviceCountByRole` or something, you could have int properties for Laptop, Peripheral, Printer, etc plus the string for the role name.  So when you do your initial GroupBy, create one class per Role (adding the name to the class) and then you iterate over all the objects you just created, and do a Where & Sum to get the counts you need

Comment: Yes, I think I see what you're getting at, then I can include the collection of this class in my 'dashboard' viewmodel. Seems I have to do a little hard coding either way, but probably not such a big issue. The problem doesn't really require a fully dynamic solution.

Comment: There are ways you can do it without hardcoding any values if thats what you are after, but you lose out on compile time warnings / strongly typed properties.

Comment: Well, it's as much an academic exercise as anything, I'm trying to learn, find out what can be done, but of course at times one comes up against a brick wall. Would you have a direction to point me re. the dynamic way? I was pondering dictionaries within dictionaries, but the syntax is so scary, especially for a Friday evening! :)

Comment: @maccettura I had a sleep an another think and came up with edit above. I'd be interested in your thoughts - is that just a ridiculous way to achieve my matrix, or a little more reasonable?